# how can i reverse a list of array in python?

Tags: python

I have a list of arrays:

```
[array([1,2,3,4],dtype=float32), array([5,6,7,8],dtype=float32)]
```

How can I reverse this list so that it looks like:

```
[array([5,6,7,8],dtype=float32), array([1,2,3,4],dtype=float32)]
```

this?

Comment: That is reversing elements in an array. what i want to do here is to reverse a list of arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use negative step:

```
from numpy import array

a = [array([1,2,3,4],dtype='float32'), array([5,6,7,8],dtype='float32')]
a[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reach with using this:

```
li = li[::-1]
```

That way, you assign li with the reversed list of lists.

Comment: Thank you. it was just a simple code!